# Вопрос по верстке, ссылки

Tags: html, vue.js

Имеется карточка, на ней на всей ссылка на страницу, кроме того есть отдельные кнопки типо добавление в избранное.
Вопрос как сделать элемент так чтобы работала именно отдельная ссылка а не общая при клике "в избранное"
в голову приходит только разность абсолютов, может есть другой способ?

Comment: нужно вам добавить больше информации (html,css,js или jpeg) - пока ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

`@click.stop` модификатор `stop` избавляет от необходимости делать абсолюты и не триггерит верхнюю ссылку